# Checkbox and text field, if one is selected or has value require other(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox

I have two checkboxes in a group and one text input. If one (or both) of the checkboxes are selected I need to have the text input be required, as well as if the text input has text I need at least one of the checkboxes to be required. Another problem I'm having it that it's using a custom templating engine (PHP backend) and is a pain to configure and get the attributes correct, another issue is it's all referenced by the name attribute and this is why I'm using a HTML5 data-group for the checkbox options which I think it working.

Any help in getting this to work, combining functions (if this makes it easier/simpler).

BTW it's running 1.3.2 jQuery

Example: (not working)

- http://jsfiddle.net/NYn8e/1/

Any suggestions?

JS:

```
function checkboxSelectedRequiredAdditionalFields(elem) {
    var passedElement = $('input:checkbox[name=' + elem + ']');

    passedElement.click(function() {
        $('input[name=number]').attr('required', true).append('<span class="required">*</span>');
        alert('text is required now?');
    });
}

function numberEnteredRequiredAdditionalFields(elem) {
    var passedElement = $('input[name=' + elem + ']');

    if (passedElement.val().length > 0) {
        var boxes = $('input[data-group=cbOptions]').click(function() {
            boxes.not(this).attr('required', false);
            alert('checkbox is selected so other checkbox is not required');
        });

        $('input[data-group=cbOptions]').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('required', true).next().append('<span class="required">*</span>');
            alert('checkbox is required now?');
        });
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="t" onclick="checkboxSelectedRequiredAdditionalFields('checkbox1');" data-group="cbOptions">
        Checkbox Option 1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="t" onclick="checkboxSelectedRequiredAdditionalFields('checkbox2');" data-group="cbOptions">
        Checkbox Option 2
    </label> 
    Number <b>
    <input type="text" name="number" value="" size="" maxlength="9" onclick="numberEnteredRequiredAdditionalFields('number');">
    </b>
</form>
```

Comment: Part of the issues it that you are assigning click handlers to the element within the same elements click event. If you look in firebug you'll see the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate the JavaScript from the HTML. **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NYn8e/6/**. If possible, remove `<b>` from the HTML source, and extend the style sheet with the right CSS property: `font-weight: bold;`.

```
<form>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="t" data-required="checkbox">
        Checkbox Option 1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="t" data-required="checkbox">
        Checkbox Option 2
    </label>
    Number <b>
    <input type="text" name="number" value="" size="" maxlength="9" data-required="number">
    </b>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function required(){
    //Any checked checkbox? checked == 0 = no, otherwise: yes
    var checked = $('input[data-required=checkbox]:checked').length;
    var $checkboxes =  $('input[data-required=checkbox]');
    var $num = $('input[name=number]');
    var length = $num.val().length;

    //Remove previously added span, if existent.
    $num.next('span.required').remove();
    $checkboxes.next('span.required').remove();
    if(!length && checked){
        $num.after('<span class="required">*</span>');
        alert("Number required!");
    } else if(length && !checked){
        $checkboxes.after('<span class="required">*</span>');
        alert("Check at least one checkbox.");
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[data-required]").change(required);
});
```

Comment: Changed it to work with my onClick/onChange events and this works great, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

=) Would this one help you?

```
<form id='myForm'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox1' value='t' id='checkbox1' onchange='alertUser()' />
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox2' value='t' id='checkbox2' onchange='alertUser()' />
    <input type='text'     name='number'              id='number'    onchange='alertUser()'/>
</form>

<script type='text/javascrip>
    function alertUser() {
        var checked1 = $('#checkbox1').attr('checked');
        var checked2 = $('#checkbox2').attr('checked');
        var number   = $('#number').val();

        if ((checked1 == true || checked2 == true) && number == '') {
           alert('Number is required!');

        } else if (number != '' && (checked1 != true && checked2 != true)) {
           alert('One of the checkbox need to be checked!');

        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately I need this to be a onclick as submit handles the required validation already

Comment: @PhillPafford: does that mean you only want to alert the user, for example, that he need to type the number when he checks 1 of the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully give you an idea on how to accomplish the task. http://jsfiddle.net/NYn8e/8/

```
var $textbox = $('input[name=number]').hide();

$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this); //store jquery object

    //get the other checkbox
    var $other= ($this.attr('name') === 'checkbox1') ? $('input[name=checkbox2]') : $('input[name=checkbox1]');

    if (!$other.is(':checked') && !$this.is(':checked')) {
        $textbox.val('').hide();
    } else{
        $textbox.show();
    }                          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">

Checkbox : <input type="checkbox"id="decline_trusted_contact" name="decline_trusted_contact"onclick="mycheckfunc()" ><br><br>

F NAME <span id="firstnameasterisks" class="astrskreqd">*</span>:  <input type="text"id="restri_trustedPersonfirstname" name="restri_trustedPersonfirstname"><br><br>
  
L NAME <span id="lastnameasterisks" class="astrskreqd">*</span>:  <input type="text"id="restri_trustedPersonlastname" name="restri_trustedPersonlastname"><br><br>
  
MOBILE <span id="mobilenumasterisks" class="astrskreqd">*</span>:  <input type="text"id="restri_trustedPersonMobilephone" name="restri_trustedPersonMobilephone"><br><br>
   
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
mycheckfunc();
function mycheckfunc(){

    var checkBox = document.getElementById("decline_trusted_contact");
     var firstname = document.getElementById("restri_trustedPersonfirstname");
     var lastname = document.getElementById("restri_trustedPersonlastname");
     var mobilenumber = document.getElementById("restri_trustedPersonMobilephone");

var fnameasterisks = document.getElementById("firstnameasterisks");
var lnameasterisks = document.getElementById("lastnameasterisks");
var mnumasterisks = document.getElementById("mobilenumasterisks");
        
     if (checkBox.checked == true){
     
         firstname.required = false;
         lastname.required = false;
         mobilenumber.required = false;
         //fnameasterisks.remove();
         //lnameasterisks.remove();
        // mnumasterisks.remove();
        fnameasterisks.style.display = "none";
        lnameasterisks.style.display = "none";
        mnumasterisks.style.display = "none";

      } else {
        firstname.required = true;
        lastname.required = true;
        mobilenumber.required = true;
         fnameasterisks.style.display = "inline";
         lnameasterisks.style.display = "inline";
         mnumasterisks.style.display = "inline";

        
      }
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a description of the code. Also, it is recommended to format the code, and remove unnecessary spaces.